# Does a browser exist for the Pi 2 that supports both WebRTC and HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: raspbian, camera, web-browsers, webrtc

I'm looking to make an application that utilises a webcam to capture a still image. Ideally, I'd like to use WebRTC and the  tag to achieve this, as this avoids a native application. Before I got model 2, I'd tried out Iceweasel, but though it supported WebRTC at the time, it lacked canvas support.

Does anyone have any experience with sa browser that's capable of this?

Answer (score 1):

[Chromium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29) is the best option for advanced web browsers on the raspberry pi as it is the most popular open source web browser. Iceweasel ([Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox)) is a close second. Popular FOSS is normally better because more people spend time improving it. More options: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers)

Approximate statistics:

- [Browser Statistics and Trends](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp)
- [Usage share of web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#Summary_table)
- [www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php)

Likely some parts of WebRTC won't be implemented on the raspberrypi like video. But as you only want to show an image there is no need for WebRTC, just use an img tag and some ajax to update it.

Comment: Hi, any facts to back that up? Not that I do not believe you it would just help the nature of this Q&A to provide more insight.

Comment: @Ghanima edited for insight

Comment: My experience with chromium is that it has lots of problems (crashes, slow and variable fps, improper reaction to flags, failure to read policies). My recommendation is to test both extensively against your application and limit screen size and flags to the minimum. Also no support for hw vpu acceleration in linux for chromium.

Answer (score -1):

[UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/news/) can stream to a browser via WebRTC.

Comment: that fails to answer the question of how to display the image on the pi.